# how to properly send a file via htmx.ajax post request method?

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to send a file via htmx.ajax() method but I had no luck, the file is not included in the post request.

```
`<!-- file input element -->
<input type="file" id="file-input">
<!-- upload button element -->
<button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
<!-- script to handle the upload logic -->
<script>
  // get the file input element
var fileInput = document.getElementById("file-input");
  // get the upload button element
  var uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload-button");
  // listen for the click event on the upload button
  uploadButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // get the file object from the input
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    // create a form data object
    var formData = new FormData();
    // append the file to the form data
    formData.append("file", file);
    // make an ajax request using htmx.ajax
    htmx.ajax("POST", "/upload", {
      body: formData
    });
  });
</script>`
```

this is the codegen link for it [LINK](https://codepen.io/samira-zwina/pen/XWybXOX)
Thank you in davance

Comment: I don't think it's possible with htmx. You can check more details on this issue here: https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/416 tl;dr ajax method does not support custom content types.
If the file is the only thing you need to upload, then you can simply use fetch instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful to know that this feature doesn't exist to look for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

I test the following script with my ASP.NET Core Web API backend located at `https://localhost:5001/api/upload` (which is specified with the `hx-post` identifier in the script) and can upload the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- load htmx library -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id='form' hx-encoding='multipart/form-data' hx-post='https://localhost:5001/api/upload'>
  <input type='file' name='file'>
  <button>Upload</button>
  <progress id='progress' value='0' max='100'></progress>
</form>
<script>
  htmx.on('#form', 'htmx:xhr:progress', function(evt) {
    htmx.find('#progress').setAttribute('value', evt.detail.loaded/evt.detail.total * 100)
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to have more control of uploading files using htmx.ajax('POST'... for example, I want to compress and resize images on the client side before sending them to the server and for this reason I need to have more control on how to process the files